# Does anyone already use or have need of comment shortcuts userscript?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts, magic-links

I've recently started using some of the shortcuts when helping clarify questions like `[mcve]` and I am aware there is a [page full of them](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting), but what I'm wanting to know is if anyone has need of, or already uses a userscript that has either shortcut keys or button clicks to inject common phrases stated during clarifying of questions.

In the long run it would be a real time-saver so I'm just curious. Anyone? If no one already has one, my plan is to write one and share it as an answer here.

Comment: Are we talking about `macro`?

Comment: @SagarV I have no idea what that is, could you provide a link?

Comment: are you refering to something like https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se

Comment: @suraj yes, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) is what you're looking for, as indicated by [suraj](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350965/does-anyone-already-use-or-have-need-of-comment-shortcuts-userscript#comment483600_350965).

You can maintain the collection of pre-baked comments off-site, in a GtiHub repo for example. The [SOCVR](https://socvr.org/) chat room does exactly that with their [autocomments](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments/tree/master/sites/stackoverflow.com) repository. Feel free to submit PR's or hop in the room if you want to discuss suggestions first.

There is also a list with comments on the Über-Meta, [Repository of useful pro-forma comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136609/repository-of-useful-pro-forma-comments) which you might find useful to use with the AutoReviewComments script.